# Building array and adding elements 'N' times

Tags: c, algorithm, tcl

I have an array

```
a[]= {34,45,65,55,67}
```

I need C or TCL code to build a new array with the each element repeated 'N' times.

For example when n=2 , resultant array should be

```
b[]= {34,34,45,45,65,65,55,55,67,67}
```

similarly when n=3, array should be

```
b[]={34,34,34,45,45,45,65,65,65,55,55,55,67,67,67}
```

How can i do this ???

Comment: This is pretty trivial; where are you stuck?

Comment: Repeating [the same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9675524/doubling-the-array-elements-in-tcl) again and again. Definitely a homework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Input parameters
int i,j;
int a[] = {34,45,65,55,67};
int aSize = 5;
int repeat = 10;

// Create a new array with a dynamic size.
// This array must be freed after to avoid memory leaks
int b* = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int) * aSize * repeat);

for (i = 0; i < aSize; ++i) // for all elements in a
    for (j = 0; j < repeat; ++j) // repeat them "repeat" times
        b[i * repeat + j] = a[i];  // i * repeat + j is the current element in b

// do something with b here

// release memory
free(b);
```

Comment: Don't do people's homework for them, it doesn't help anybody.

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill roger that.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a TCL solution:

```
% package require struct
2.1
% proc dup {items count} {
     return [join [struct::list mapfor x $items {struct::list repeat $count $x}]]
}
% dup {1 2 3} 3
1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3
```